# Latin word for a person who eats meat but not fish

Tags: word-choice

In Latin, meat is called "carnis". Is there a specific Latin word or expression for a person who eats meat but not fish or seafood in general? Is "carnitarian" a Latin word?

Comment: Are you looking for a Latin word, or an English word of Latin origin? If it's the latter, I can move this to the English site where they would better be able to help.

Comment: @cmw Right now I am looking for a Latin word. If I want to ask about an English word of Latin origin, I will ask that as a separate question on https://english.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I asked because a word like "carnitarian", your example, would be English, not Latin.

Comment: Modern concepts like this usually don't have a direct translation in Latin. They are typically expressed using a periphrasis, such as "qui/quae solum carnem edit" (he/she who only eats meat).

Comment: Here's Pomponius Mela describing what we would call a "pescatarian": "quidam nullum animal occidere, nulla carne vesci optimum existimant, quosdam tantum pisces alunt."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Carnitarian" is not a Latin word, no. The Latin equivalent would be *carnivorus*, the ancestor of English "carnivore"—literally, "flesh-eating".

However, fish can be considered *caro* in Classical Latin, and thus a *carnivorus* creature can still eat them. For example, from Pliny the Elder:

> Omnia autem **carnivora** sunt talia et supina vescuntur, ut in delphinis diximus, et cum ceteri pisces ova pariant, hoc genus solum, ut ea quae cete appellant, animal parit, excepta quam ranam vocant.
>
> *All of these sorts [of cartilaginous fish] are **carnivorous**, and feed lying on their backs, as we've said about dolphins, and while other fish lay eggs, this type alone, like the one they name the "cete", gives birth to live offspring, except the one they call the "rana".*

(*Rana* here is the common monkfish, according to Lewis and Short; *cete* is presumably some kind of whale but I don't know which.)

Since this is a passage about fish, presumably the *caro* they eat is other fish rather than terrestrial creatures. I'm not aware of any Latin word that refers to all non-fish meat—there are words for specific types, but not a general term that excludes fish.

However, if you're looking at Ecclesiastical Latin, you're in luck! Doctrinally, fish is not considered *caro* by the Roman Catholic Church—this matters for Lent purposes, where people are supposed to abstain from *caro* on specific days but can eat fish (including some odd exceptions like capybaras).

So if you wanted to use *carnivorus* to mean "eating meat but not fish", you could always say you're using it in the Catholic sense, where a *carnivorus* eats beef, pork, and chicken, but *not* fish or capybaras.

Comment: I wonder to what extent this is in fact due to the Catholic Church. "Flesh-meat" meant (and still means) "all meat except seafood." I noticed that Thomas Aquinas *sometimes* uses *caro* to the exclusion of *piscis* and *sometimes* talks about *caro piscium*.